# NodeJS MySQL Advanced query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, date

I have tables and such data

```
   id   |   time
   1    |   1578011011791
   2    |   1578011012791
   3    |   1578011112791
   4    |   1578171212791
   5    |   1578171315791
```

I want to know how many results from a given day are, approximating each time in milliseconds to yy/mm/dd

> In javascript -> (1578171315791).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

- 2019/01/03 - 1, 2,3
- 2019/01/04 - 4, 5

So result will be:

```
2019/01/03 -> 3
2019/01/04 -> 2
```

That is, to briefly approximate milliseconds to date and count result.

How to do it using query in mysql?

Comment: You need to `select count(id)` and use `GROUP BY date(time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime()` to convert your epoch timestamp to a `datetime` value and then turn it to a `date` with function `date()`. The rest is aggregation:

```
select date(from_unixtime(time/1000)) dy, count(*)
from mytable
group by dy
order by dy
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f09fa680bb553ff21e124d5500b0926)**:

```
dy         | count(*)
:--------- | -------:
2020-01-03 |        3
2020-01-04 |        2
```